# pandas read_csv for a gziped file is not infering numeric columns types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I read a CSV file using:

```
train_data= pd.read_csv("train.pk", header=True, encoding='Latin-1')
```

I get all columns types inferred quite accurately. For example `IDs` with any length are inferred `int64`.

Now doing the same, with a gziped file, pandas infer them as Objects.

```
train_data= pd.read_csv("train.pk", header=0, compression='gzip', encoding='Latin-1')
```

Interestingly, numbers that as 5 or less digits, are inferred as int64.

I don't want to manually apply `pandas.to_numeric` on every column, because I have dozens.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: can you provide a small __reproducible__ data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate your issue. However, downcasting need not be a manual process. You can select integer columns via [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64'),
                   'b': pd.Series([10000000, 20000000, 300000000], dtype='int64')})

numerics = ['int8', 'int16', 'int32', 'int64']

for col in df.select_dtypes(include=numerics).columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast='integer')

print(df.dtypes)

a     int8
b    int32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce what you mean. Add more details

```
$ cat /tmp/train.csv
id,name
100001,facebook
20000,google
300001,apple
$ cat /tmp/train.csv | gzip >   /tmp/train.csv.gz
$ python
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv("/tmp/train.csv").dtypes
id       int64
name    object
dtype: object
>>> pd.read_csv("/tmp/train.csv.gz", compression="gzip").dtypes
id       int64
name    object
dtype: object
>>>
```